# Explanation of several TX and RX data pins in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have been doing VHDL for a while, but still i am a beginner.
I have a UART code, and its working perfectly, but unable to understand the use of few pins

Please explain me the use of following pins
txReady_o,rxNewData_o,rxDataAck_i

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Entity
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
entity uart_mod is
generic (CLK_FREQ : integer := 18500000;
BAUDRATE : integer := 115200);  
port (
-- general ports
clk_i       : in  std_logic;
rst_i       : in  std_logic;
-- tx ports
tx_o        : out std_logic;        -- transmit data line        
txData_i    : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);  -- data to transmit
txReady_o   : out std_logic;        -- transmit ready flag
txStart_i   : in  std_logic;        -- start transmission signal
-- rx ports
rx_i        : in  std_logic;        -- receive data line
rxData_o    : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);  -- received data
rxNewData_o : out std_logic;        -- new data received flag
rxDataAck_i : in  std_logic;        -- acknowledge of received data signal
rxErr_o     : out std_logic);       -- receive error
end uart_mod;

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Architecture
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
architecture Behavioral of uart_mod is

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Constants
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- sample values
constant BIT_COUNT_DIV1 : integer := CLK_FREQ/BAUDRATE - 1;
constant BIT_COUNT_DIV2 : integer := CLK_FREQ/BAUDRATE/2 - 1;
constant BIT_COUNT_DIV4 : integer := CLK_FREQ/BAUDRATE/4 - 1;
constant MAX_BIT_ERROR  : integer := BIT_COUNT_DIV2/3;  -- 33% errors allowed

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Signals
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- tx signals
signal txWaitCnt : integer range 0 to BIT_COUNT_DIV1;
signal txBitCnt  : integer range 0 to 7;

type txStates is (idle, startBit, dataBit, stopBit);
signal txState : txStates;

-- rx signals 
signal rxInput   : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal rxTrigger : std_logic;
signal rxSync    : std_logic;
signal rxWeight  : integer range 0 to 5;
signal sampleCnt : integer range 0 to BIT_COUNT_DIV2 + BIT_COUNT_DIV4;
signal dataCnt   : integer range 0 to 8;
signal highCnt   : integer range 0 to BIT_COUNT_DIV2;

type rxStates is (idle, startBit, waitState, dataBit, stopBit, resetCycle);
signal rxState    : rxStates;
type rxAckStates is (idle, waitAck);
signal rxAckState : rxAckStates;

-- debug signals
signal txState_as_vector    : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal rxState_as_vector    : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal rxAckState_as_vector : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);

begin

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Transmit FSM
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
txMonitor : process (clk_i)
begin
if rising_edge(clk_i) then
-- sync reset
if rst_i = '1' then
txState   <= idle;
tx_o      <= '1';
txReady_o <= '1';
txBitCnt  <= 0;
txWaitCnt <= 0;
else
-- debug signal
txState_as_vector <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(txStates'pos(txState), 4));

case txState is

when idle =>
---------------------------------------------------------------------
-- State 0: Idle and wait for tx request
---------------------------------------------------------------------

if txStart_i = '1' then
tx_o      <= '0';
txReady_o <= '0';
txState   <= startBit;
end if;

when startBit =>
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- State 1: Send startbit
-------------------------------------------------------------------

-- check if max cnt value is reached
if txWaitCnt < BIT_COUNT_DIV1 then
txWaitCnt <= txWaitCnt + 1;
else
txWaitCnt <= 0;
txState   <= dataBit;
tx_o      <= txData_i(txBitCnt);
end if;

when dataBit =>
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- State 2: Send data bits
-------------------------------------------------------------------

-- check if max cnt value is reached
if txWaitCnt < BIT_COUNT_DIV1 then
txWaitCnt <= txWaitCnt + 1;
else
txWaitCnt <= 0;
-- check if all bits are transmitted              
if txBitCnt < 7 then
txBitCnt <= txBitCnt + 1;
tx_o     <= txData_i(txBitCnt + 1);
else
txBitCnt <= 0;
txState  <= stopBit;
tx_o     <= '1';
end if;
end if;

when stopBit =>
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- State 3: Send stop bit
-------------------------------------------------------------------

-- check if max cnt value is reached
if txWaitCnt < BIT_COUNT_DIV1 then
txWaitCnt <= txWaitCnt + 1;
else
txWaitCnt <= 0;
txReady_o <= '1';
txState   <= idle;
end if;

end case;
end if;
end if;
end process txMonitor;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- 3-of-5 rx sample filter with shifter
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
process (clk_i) is
begin  -- process
if rising_edge(clk_i) then
-- sync reset
if rst_i = '1' then
rxWeight <= 0;
rxInput  <= (others => '0');
else
-- increase or decrease rxWeight
if rx_i = '1' and rxWeight < 5 then
rxWeight <= rxWeight + 1;
elsif rx_i = '0' and rxWeight > 0 then
rxWeight <= rxWeight - 1;
end if;
-- rx shifter with respect to rxWeight
if rxWeight > 2 then
rxInput <= rxInput(6 downto 0) & '1';
else
rxInput <= rxInput(6 downto 0) & '0';
end if;
end if;
end if;
end process;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Receive FSM
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
rxMonitor : process (clk_i)
begin
if rising_edge(clk_i) then
-- sync reset
if rst_i = '1' then
-- initial state
rxState   <= idle;
-- reset signals
rxTrigger <= '0';
rxSync    <= '0';
-- reset output ports
rxErr_o   <= '0';
rxData_o  <= (others => '0');
-- reset counter
sampleCnt <= 0;
highCnt   <= 0;
dataCnt   <= 0;
else
-- debug signal
rxState_as_vector <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(rxStates'pos(rxState), 4));

case rxState is
when idle =>
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- State 0: Idle and wait for a falling edge (start bit)
-------------------------------------------------------------------

-- check rx input for a falling edge
if rxInput(1 downto 0) = "10" then
rxState <= startBit;
sampleCnt <= 1;
end if;

when startBit =>
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- State 1: Check if falling edge results in a start bit
-------------------------------------------------------------------

-- sample 3/4 bit
if sampleCnt < (BIT_COUNT_DIV2 + BIT_COUNT_DIV4) then
sampleCnt <= sampleCnt + 1;
-- sum up bit errors
if rxInput(0) = '1' then
if highCnt > MAX_BIT_ERROR then
rxErr_o <= '1';
rxState <= resetCycle;
else
highCnt <= highCnt + 1;
end if;
end if;
else
-- start bit detected
rxState   <= waitState;
sampleCnt <= 0;
highCnt   <= 0;
end if;

when waitState =>
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- State 2: Wait for bit/2 and try to sync if there is a stable edge
-------------------------------------------------------------------

if sampleCnt < BIT_COUNT_DIV2 then
-- increase counter
sampleCnt <= sampleCnt + 1;
-- try to sync
if rxSync = '0' then
if rxInput = "00001111" or rxInput = "11110000" then
sampleCnt <= BIT_COUNT_DIV4 + 4;
rxSync    <= '1';
end if;
end if;
else
-- wait time reached
sampleCnt <= 0;
rxSync    <= '0';
-- check if all data bits are sampled
if dataCnt < 8 then
rxState <= dataBit;
else
dataCnt <= 0;
rxState <= stopBit;
end if;
end if;

when dataBit =>
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- State 3: Receive a data bit
-------------------------------------------------------------------

if sampleCnt < BIT_COUNT_DIV2 then
sampleCnt <= sampleCnt + 1;
if rxInput(0) = '1' then
highCnt <= highCnt + 1;
end if;
else
sampleCnt <= 0;
highCnt   <= 0;
rxState   <= waitState;
dataCnt   <= dataCnt + 1;

-- sampling complete, check highCnt
if (BIT_COUNT_DIV2 - highCnt) <= MAX_BIT_ERROR then
-- '1' was sampled
rxData_o(dataCnt) <= '1';
elsif highCnt <= MAX_BIT_ERROR then
-- '0' was sampled
rxData_o(dataCnt) <= '0';
else
-- sample error
rxErr_o <= '1';
rxState <= resetCycle;
end if;
end if;

when stopBit =>
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- State 4: Receive the stop bit
-------------------------------------------------------------------

if sampleCnt < BIT_COUNT_DIV2 then
sampleCnt <= sampleCnt + 1;
if rxInput(0) = '0' then
if highCnt > MAX_BIT_ERROR then
-- stop bit error
rxErr_o <= '1';
rxState <= resetCycle;
else
highCnt <= highCnt + 1;
end if;
end if;
else
-- stop bit detected
rxState   <= resetCycle;
rxTrigger <= '1';
end if;

when resetCycle =>
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- State 5: cycle to reset flags and counters
-------------------------------------------------------------------
highCnt   <= 0;
rxTrigger <= '0';
rxErr_o   <= '0';
rxState   <= idle;

end case;
end if;
end if;
end process rxMonitor;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Acknowledge handshake
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ackProcess : process (clk_i) is
begin  -- process ackProcess
if rising_edge(clk_i) then
-- sync reset
if rst_i = '1' then
rxAckState <= idle;
else
-- debug signal
rxAckState_as_vector <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(rxAckStates'pos(rxAckState), 2));

case rxAckState is
when idle =>
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- State 0: Wait for new received data
-------------------------------------------------------------------

-- check if rx data is available
if rxTrigger = '1' then
rxAckState <= waitAck;
end if;

when waitAck =>
-------------------------------------------------------------------
-- State 1: Wait for a external ackowlede
-------------------------------------------------------------------

if rxDataAck_i = '1' then
rxAckState <= idle;
end if;

end case;
end if;
end if;
end process ackProcess;

rxNewData_o <= '1' when rxAckState = waitAck else '0';

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: ***PLEASE*** stop ***SHOUTING*** at us ! Writing in ALL CAPS is annoying, because it's really hard to read, and it's considered ***shouting*** at your audience which is just plain rude and offensive. **Don't do it!** and fix your title right now

Comment: Its just a heading, nothing like shouting

Comment: I am ne here, i dnt even know how to fix it

Comment: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: First of all - the fact that ALL CAPS is considered SHOUTING is **universal** - this is not a SO specific thing. **All** forums frown upon ALL CAPS. And second: you can **edit** your post and fix the title !

Answer (score 0):

Liberal interpretations of the verb SHOUT aside, an examination of the VHDL design specification provided shows that the signals `txReady_o`,`rxNewData_o` and `rxDataAck_i` are part of the clock (`clk_i`) synchronous handshaking to operate the two parallel interfaces for transmitting and receiving data either sent serially or received serially.

> I have a UART code, and its working perfectly, but unable to understand the use of few pins

Besides wondering how you can determine the code works without using the interfaces, each of the parallel transmit and receive interfaces uses a two signal handshake.  (And no this is not serial flow control).

***Two signal hand shake for transmit***
The transmitter signifies that new data can be accepted by asserting `txReady_o`.  When data to be transmitted is made available on `txData_i` the input `txStart_i` is asserted until `txReady_o` is de-asserted (after the next clk_i rising edge, see the `tx_Monitor` process, case `tx_State`, `when idle`).

***Two signal hand shake for receive*** 
The receiver signifies a received data value with `rxNewData_o` and after that data is read from the `rxData_o` port `rxDataAck_i` is asserted. `rxNewData_o` is de-asserted as a result similar to `txReady_o`, see process `ackProcess`. `rxDataAck_i` should likewise be de-asserted when `rxNewData_o` is de-asserted.

Note that you the time from the stop bit being detected until next first received data bit (following a start bit) to read `rxData_o`. There is no separate output buffer nor output FIFO.

Comment: Thank you very much, the answer was very useful.
I an trying to echo each byte. Its like i give input from keybroad and i can see the same on screen again.I am using cutecom as gui.
I have written a design and its working almost as expected. But problem is if i am typing a letter, it is getting echoed infinite number of times, however it should stop as soon as one byte is echoed and start waiting.
Now  i am using a FSM , with WAITING and FORWARDING states, but unable to understand which pin to check for wait operation. Is it rxNewData_o pin ??

Comment: You shouldn't read rxData_o unless rxNewData_o is asserted.  You acknowledge you've read it by asserting rxDataAck_i.  You can use the handshaking to stall the interface by preventing rxDataAck_i from being asserted when rxNewData_o is not asserted.